# cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time

Tags: rust

I don't understand this borrow checker error:

```
pub fn wait_for_device(&mut self) -> RoxResult<hidapi::HidDevice> {
    let mut device = self.open_device();
    let start = time::Instant::now();
    while device.is_err() {
        device = self.open_device();
        if start.elapsed().as_secs() > 30 {
            return Err("Can't reconnect to device".to_owned());
        }
    }
    Ok(device.expect("Out of while so we should have a device"))
}

pub fn open_device(&mut self) -> RoxResult<hidapi::HidDevice> {
    let device_info = &self.list[0]; 
    if let Ok(device) = self.api.open(device_info.vendor_id, device_info.product_id) {
        self.current_device = Some(device_info.clone());
        Ok(device)
    } else {
        Err(format!(
            "Error opening device vip: {:x} pid: {:x}",
            device_info.vendor_id, device_info.product_id
        ))
    }
}
```

---

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src\usb.rs:64:22
   |
61 |         let mut device = self.open_device();
   |                          ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
64 |             device = self.open_device();
   |                      ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
70 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here
```

I thought my first borrowing will end at the end of `open_device` but it seems I'm wrong. Why?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Ideally, produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org). There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: In my case, I was missing a lifetime annotation in the return type -> HidDevice<'a>
Just to make sure this is not the case for you, turn on #![deny(elided_lifetimes_in_paths)] and fix all the warnings

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Variables are valid until the end of the scope in which they were declared. You created a variable `device` and assigned borrowed value to it in the scope of the entire function. In other words the borrow ends at the end of the function (as you can see in compiler error message).

Comment: I don't get it, the compiler is complaining about `self`, not `device`.

Comment: Because the problem is not `device` itself but the fact that you have mutably borrowed `self` twice in the same scope.

Comment: How do we write this in Rust then? I want to keep trying open_device as long as I don't have a HidDevice back :-/

Comment: Got it, HidDevice has a lifetime and no clone (which makes sense to manage the usb connection), I can't keep it if there's a chance to lose it. I'll call open_device only when sending/receiving data and let the device Drop.

Answer (score 0):

Re-posting this as an answer since it took me a long time to find a solution for this compiler error:

In my case, I was missing a lifetime annotation in the return type:

```
pub fn open_device(&mut self) -> RoxResult<hidapi::HidDevice<'a>> {
                                              add this ---- ^^^^
```

Just to make sure this is not the case for you, turn on `#![deny(elided_lifetimes_in_paths)]` at the top of your `src/lib.rs` or `src/main.rs` and fix all the warnings

This might not be the solution for your case but the error message I was getting was identical and this might help someone else.